# fetch value from an array of arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

I have used login through facebook on my website, and after login I am fetching values and profession of user.

I used:

```
$work = $me['work'];
```

code to get the work history and got the data in an array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [employer] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 178191330369
                    [name] => Office
                )

            [position] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 106011616105574
                    [name] => Students
                )

            [start_date] => 0000-00
        )
)
```

now I wish to get the value students from the array. for this I used

```
$totalwork = $work['position']['name'];
echo '<pre>';
print_r($totalwork);
echo '</pre>';
```

but I am not able to fetch value from the array. How can it be done?

Comment: $totalwork = $work[0]['position']['name'];

Comment: @donald123 thnks it worked